# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ToastrService -> InjectionToken ToastConfig]: in tslint angular 8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, eslint, ngx-toastr

When i run the unit testing in angular 8 project, i found an error in ngx-toastr

> NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ToastrService -> InjectionToken ToastConfig]:

And i imported the requierd modules in the spec.ts file, And also i declared forRoot() in app.module.ts

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [MatTabsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    ToastrModule
  ],
  declarations: [CommunicationComponent],
  providers: [
    ToastrService,
  ]
})
  .compileComponents();
```

}));

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ToastrModule.forRoot()],

    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Add ToastrModule.forRoot() in imports as shown above and your error might be resolved

Answer (score 3):

These approaches did not work for me. I had to provide my own value for the provider. 
This is what worked for me:

First, I declared my own "dummy" implementation:

```
const toastrService = {
    success: (message?: string, title?: string, override?: Partial<IndividualConfig>) => { },
    error: (message?: string, title?: string, override?: Partial<IndividualConfig>) => { }
  };
```

Then, I indicated the value to use in the providers section:

```
providers: [
        ...
        { provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastrService },
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the providers like below

```
providers: [
  {provide: ToastrService, useClass: ToastrService}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to add `.forRoot()`

Just add this way in your module.ts

`ToastrModule.forRoot()`